# OpenVPN to access restriced pages

Tags: ip, openvpn

I  am looking for a method  to  go  out with  different  ip in order  to access  some  sites  that are blocked by my local provider(I need to  write scripts   to retrieve  data from thos   pages).On Windows  I have  proxyes, but  now migrating  to  Ubuntu due to  better workinng with ipython notebooks   for a specific  kernel  I need to  do  the same.
Hoewer I am interested if cand I  do this  with open source  things and not  to  depend on proxyes located in other locations.
As  I  understand  doing some research on the  web  there is a  possibility with  open vpn  that if I understand correct  allows to  make this trick  with private network inside  wan network and ssh tunneling   but  my knowledge   in this domain is very poor .Could  this community help me  with this issue?Tnks!

Answer (score 0):

On very high level, the VPN end-point wouldn't be any different from a proxy server: Traffic between your system and the destination pass through the remote "middle point" (VPN server or proxy), and thus can bypass restrictions enforced to direct connections. Using a VPN would just make the traffic between the "middle point" more secure, but if using proxies works, then there's no benefit of the additional encryption.

```
your system <-------> proxy or VPN end-point <-------> target system
```

How would you be using the VPN tunnel varies based on the service being provided. You mention SSH tunnel, but that would require the VPN end-point being such that also provides SSH access, and doing SSH over a VPN tunnel would just be putting two layers of encryption over each other (inefficient).

If you are talking about those free openVPN services which allow one to use some remote end-point, then you would just be using a browser in a similar way as with proxies (you mentioned pages, I assume you refer to HTTP traffic / WWW). If the VPN tunnel is configured so that it acts as your default route (thus all traffic on that network interface would be passed through the tunnel), then you would be accessing the target site directly, by typing its address in the browser's address bar. If, however, the VPN tunnel just tunnels a specific subnet (subset of the IP address space), then it would not be good for your purposes unless you can manage adding a proxy at the end-point (and again we'd making the original simple idea just more complicated) or some sort of address translation or routing to the target.

So, if your intent is to just access web pages over HTTP, and the need for a proxy is solely based on simple access control which can be by-passed by using a proxy, and you do not fear for being punished for bypassing those access controls (e.g. are not a human rights activist under repressive regime, just go with the proxies. I don't think the open/free openVPN services are any more "open source" than the proxies you've been using (Apache, the most common web server, can also act as a proxy...), or otherwise "better", on contrary I have personally pretty bad experience of them which made me set up my own openVPN server (but then again my purpose was to secure my network access in open hotspots, for which using VPN is a good solution).